# Generating random number error

Tags: php

I am testing a php function i found on the php documentation based on this comment:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php#108861

```
<?php

    function RandNumber($e) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < $e; $i++) {
            $rand =  $rand .  rand(0, 9);  
        }
        return $rand;
    }

    echo RandNumber(4);
    // Outputs a 6 digit random number
?>
```

I get the error Notice:

> Undefined variable: rand in /var/www/eod.php on line 7

This is line 7:

```
$rand =  $rand . rand(0, 9);
```

Why is causing this error since the function works as expected?

Comment: It's just a warning, if you initialize $rand to '' it will disappear.

Comment: Why not use: `rand(1000000000, 9999999999);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your `$rand` variable to remove this warning :

```
 function RandNumber($e){
     $rand="";
     for($i=0;$i<$e;$i++){
        $rand =  $rand.rand(0, 9);  
     }
     return $rand;
 }
```

Note that you may simplify your code :

```
 function RandNumber($e){
     $rand="";
     for(;$e-->0;){ // no need for an additional variable
        $rand .= rand(0, 9); // addition and assignement with one operator  
     }
     return $rand;
 }
```

Comment: Or you could simplify the entire silly thing to a single mt_rand call?

Comment: Uuuuuh, the pointy thingy `-->` operator... O。O Maybe not the most readable. ;-)

Comment: @deceze I like it. I see it as an arrow : "go to zero" :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha this simplification wouldn't allow big numbers and wouldn't build strings starting with "0" (at least without an additional formatting step).

Comment: @dystroy: This is PHP, not C, if you need it to be a string, it would be a string. No one said he wanted big numbers, he wanted a six digit random number. And even with this additional formatting step, my method is still more efficient (and more readable) than yours.

Answer (score 2):

To output a random 6 digit number (If you need larger numbers, greater than `mt_getrandmax()`, this solution would fail), simply use

```
mt_rand(100000, 999999);
```

To include numbers with leading zeros (`000123`), you can use a combination of `my_rand(0, 999999)` and `str_pad($number, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

No need for fancy looping.

Comment: Well, you can't generate numbers larger than `mt_getrandmax()` this way. For 6 digit numbers though, I agree.

Comment: Indeed. Only if you plan to output very large random numbers, you should be using such a function.

Comment: This won't be able to generate '000123' though.

Comment: @Jack: Thought of that, in that case you can use mt_rand(0, 999999) and use str_pad().

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error.. it's a notice message.. If you don't want to appear that notice you should define it before doing the loop:

```
$rand = '';

for($i=0;$i<$e;$i++){
 $rand =  $rand .  rand(0, 9);  
}
```